# Java Web Start приложения не могут быть запущены стандартным способом после установки JRE j2se 1.8.0_181

Tags: безопасность, java

Выводит сообщение:

Application Blocked by Deployment Rule Set

For security, applications must now meet the requirements for the High or Very High security settings, or be part of the Exception Site List, to be allowed to run.

[More:](https://java.com/de/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Deployment Rule Set required Java version 1.8.0_60 is not available or incompatible with version 1.8+ requested by the Application.

Редактирование правил **deployment rule set** (а именно обновление атрибута `version` не принесло результатов).

Однако продолжает работать запуск offline приложений из кэша в том числе о только что скачанных (но которые не могли быть запущены стандартным способом и-за проблем с секъюрностью). Согласно логам консоли в этом случае работает старая версия рантайма.

Вопросы :

1. Как правильно обновить правила для новой версии JRE с удаленным
   уровнем защиты Средний.
2. Ищутся сторонние утилиты по расширенному управлению локально установленными в кэше приложениями.
3. Связана ли эта проблема с последовательным удалением технологии JWS из стека Java?

Comment: Реквестирую тег "javapocalypse"

Comment: В панели java надо добавить адреса в список исключения.

Comment: А если это невозможно? Я могу править только ruleset

Comment: обратите внимание на другие способы распространения приложений. Наиболее похожий будет getDown;

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ooo-libs/y3hpqa8nzrw

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ooo-libs/RV6bMpc5wOk

Comment: https://github.com/threerings/getdown/issues/132

Comment: там можно перечислить список файлов, которые подлежат "слежению для обновления". Я тоже несколько заманался смотреть какие из зависимостей надо отредактировать, поэтому сделал отдельный модуль, который редактирует файл со списком файлов исходя из содержимого в собранной папке и генерирует диги. Руками постоянно что-то да забудешь добавить/скопировать.

Comment: OK, Google:

https://github.com/threerings/getdown/issues/132#issuecomment-418614563